# why minikube ssh is very slow but directly ssh is fast?

Tags: docker, ssh, minikube

I installed minikube v0.28.0 in Mac10.12

after starting I'd like to ssh login to the vm

if I use the `minikube ssh`, it will take about 30 seconds before login,

but when I use the `ssh docker@192.168.64.2`, the login succeed at once.

I don't why the minikube command is so slow?

btw, I have tried two vm drivers, virtualbox and hyperkit, they both have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the reason:

every time minikube run it will make a update checking!

it will pull the latest version info from its distribute server.

so huge time is wasted in the network operation.

how do I found this?

use the command below:

`minikube --logtostderr -v 9 ssh`

then a log line shows:

`I0723 17:58:00.368814 5385 notify.go:121] Checking for updates...`

after searching the source, now there's no option for disableing this, since the control variable `enableUpdateNotification` in `root.go` is always `true`.